# How to Maintain Persistent R Package Installations Across R Sessions in Google Colab?

Tags: r, tags, google-colaboratory, libraries

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am currently using Google Colab  for my R projects and facing a challenge with persistent installation of R packages. Each time I start a new Colab notebook session, I have to reinstall all the packages, which is time-consuming. (8 to 10 minutes every time)

I tried saving my environment using `save.image()` and loading it in new sessions, but the libraries don't seem to be installed upon reloading. Here is what I did:

1. Mounted drive in a python cell
2. Changed environment to R
3. Installed necessary packages (8 minutes)
4. Saved the environment with `save.image(file = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_R_environment.RData")` and confirmed the file was there.
5. In a new R session, loaded this environment with `load("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_R_environment.RData")`.

The process went smooth, with no errors, however, the packages don't seem to be recognized in the new session and the libraries don't work. I am aware that Colab provides an ephemeral environment, but I am looking for a way to make my package installation persistent across sessions.

Is there a recommended way to achieve persistent package installation in Google Colab  for R? Or is there a more efficient method to handle this situation that I might be missing?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Leo